# Google ranking - Modal views - google analytics events

Tags: google-analytics, google-ranking, modal-view

I modified a site recently :
- I added many google analytics events, to better understand user behaviour.
- I added also two buttons on almost all the pages of the site. Those buttons show modal-views (I am using bootstrap) with questions about user opinion. This modals views are on almost all pages of the site.

After this modification the ranking of the site decreased on google search from the second place to the seconde page :(

Is it the events-collected or the model-views added ?
If the model-views are the reason, then how to better do similar surveys ?

Did you have please similar experience, or explanation to this ?

Comment: Much more likely it was Googles recent Panda4 Update (starting 21st of May and ongoing). Search ranking is not affected by Google Analytics.

Comment: We worked hard to have good content. How to know what's wrong? Could we know what is differently mesured with this new update, if it is not a black screen by google?

Comment: Maybe pages that link to you have been downgraded and your page rank has been hit as a consequence since referring pages have less rank to pass on? In any case, better ask at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/. SO is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely due to the recent modifications you made on your pages. Those are neutral. May be Google or users found "better" or more valuable pages than yours. Maybe Google has changed the criteria it uses to rank pages in your niche.